vimux plugin for Neovim via Flatpak "failed to find executable tmux"
For the first time, I am trying to use neovim after installing it with Flatpak.
As requirements for other things, I am using vimux.
When I run neovim, I get the message "failed to find executable tmux".
I am pretty new to Flatpak. I (kind of) understand it runs apps in isolation. I had to look up how to use XDG directories for Neovim via Flatpak to use the default configuration path. But here, I am lost and I did not find lots of results on Google for my scenario.
Can anyone explain to me what's going on and how to fix this eventually?

EDIT: It looks like people are devaluating this question but you're probably missing the fact that I have tmux installed. I use it extensively on a daily basis.

Vimux needs is tmux installed in the system, something like:
pacman -S tmux

or
brew install tmux

More accurate commands for specific systems can be found in the official documentation.

I have tmux installed. I use it extensively on a daily basis.
